# Spyder: No Python shell is currently selected

Tags: python, shell, spyder

After I updated packages for python (matplotlib specifically), Spyder cannot find Python shell anymore. Upon running any script, I get 
"Python 2.7.6 64bits, Qt 4.8.6, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.10.4 on Linux"

Also, for any of the consoles I open, I get a blank window. No usual >>>. The workspace doesn't load the values for pi and e as it would normally do

Many other online Q&A are about fixing the settings in preferences->run. Though that doesn't change anything for me

I got Spyder 2.2.5 and
Python 2.7.6 64bits, Qt 4.8.6, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.10.4 on Linux

I would be thankful for any help. What should I do?

Comment: What Linux distro do you use?

Comment: My kernel version is 4.2.0-36-generic. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Found solution:

Summary: reinstall spyder via pip.

In the process, in installed and reinstalled Spyder few times. Though that didn't help. After reading another Q&A, I figured I should install Spyder via pip. That worked:

```
sudo pip install spyder
```

Thanks for the help!